# Where to find the pdb files for Qt's dll?

Tags: c++, qt, pdb-files

I am debugging a Qt application. Where can I find Qt's debug dll?
I am using vs2010 on windows. It says it needs the pdb file for many .dll from Qt.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Qt SDK does not come with debugging symbols for release builds. You have to compile the whole thing from source with the correct compiler flags to get the .pdb files you need.

See this [bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-3934).

Comment: Why would you need to debug `Qt`?

Comment: Two points:1. I want to find the pdb files for debug build not release? It seems there at least is one for debug build? 2. Because I have met a bug as in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26673955/is-this-the-safe-way-to-use-qsql-data-base-in-qt which I would like to have a look what happened in addDatabase() function.

Comment: @Nyaruko You should see dmitry-sazonov's comment as to where to find the debug .pdbs (%QTDIR%\bin e.g. C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013\bin)

Comment: @luliu For debugging problems that only happen in release, for debugging crash dump files, for using profiling and performance analysis tools and so on.

Answer (score 18):

As of Qt 5.9, the PDBs corresponding to the Windows distros are available as a separate .zip file for download from this archive:
https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/

Just browse to your specific distro and pick between the "uwp" or the "desktop" PDBs as appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

As found in this [bugreport](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-72733), the PDB files for Qt 5.12 can now be installed through the **Online Installer** (Maintenance Tool) (under the name **Debug Information Files**).

Comment: Works well, although you need to check "Debug Information Files" AND the distribution you want, otherwise, of course, you won't have any .pdb files (which happened to me the first time). So it seems you need to download everything again.

Answer (score 3):

The path is deep and difficult to find. As for `Qt` `5.15.1`, it seems like this:
https://download.qt.io/online/qtsdkrepository/windows_x86/desktop/qt5_5151/qt.qt5.5151.debug_info.win32_msvc2019/

Answer (score 1):

I found this files inside of bin folder of my Qt installation (qt 5.7)

Answer (score 1):

I found debug symbol for Qt 5.10.0 at: https://download.qt.io/new_archive/qt/5.10/5.10.0/

You can go to parent directory and check whether your searching version is there.

Answer (score 0):

`PDB`s are used for debugging, if you install the `Qt` library you won't be able to get inside the library with the debugger and step inside the implementation of a function for example...which is the way it has to be. AFAIK, if you want the `PDB`s you need to compile `Qt` from source.

Comment: You are wrong. PDB files for debug builds are located at `%QTDIR%\bin` folder. PDB files for plugins are located at each plugin folder.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov And how would you debug if you don't have the *.cpp source files, for example?

Comment: You can't debug w/o source files. But stacktrace for user code will be always complete, if you will have pdb files. I'm not talking about sources. PDB files and Qt sources are coming with all pre-compiled qt packages.

Answer (score 0):

I tried follow @LittleWhite 's method, i find qt online installer download debug info from here (qt 5.14.2 msvc2017, x86)

```
http://mirror.bit.edu.cn/qtproject/online/qtsdkrepository/windows_x86/desktop/qt5_5142/qt.qt5.5142.debug_info.win32_msvc2017/
```

The entity packge may be vary large, qtbase is needed and is enough for most of us.

```
5.14.2-0-202003291224qtbase-Windows-Windows_10-MSVC2017-Windows-Windows_10-X86-debug-symbols.7z
```

Answer (score 0):

There are not old QT versions in the online installer. I was able to download `5.9.12` PDB files from [here](https://download.qt.io/online/qtsdkrepository/windows_x86/desktop/qt5_5129/qt.qt5.5129.debug_info.win64_msvc2017_64). To get files for other versions or platforms, change ..5129.. in the link or navigate manually from the root [online installer repository](https://download.qt.io/online/qtsdkrepository/)