# Debug a Qt assert in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am getting an assert that generates a dialog from Qt to abort, retry, or ignore. Unfortunately, when I retry, it always just goes to `app.exec()` so I cannot see where the error is coming from, or what inputs may be contributing.

When I debug, I can see all my code and moc code, and all variables and pointers are set appropriately. But when I step into Qt code, I get `Qt5Cored.pdb not loaded`. I cannot seem to locate the PDB files in my Qt installation either.

The error happens after emitting a signal and all (my) slots have completed successfully.

The error from Qt is so deep in the weeds, it is not helpful:

```
Debug Error!

Program: Qt5Cored.dll
Module: 5.14.2
File: painting\qoutlinemapper.cpp
Line: 105

ASSERT: '!path.isEmpty()' in file painting\qoutlinemapper.cpp, line 105

(Press Retry to debug the process)
```

I inspected the [source code](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/gui/painting/qoutlinemapper.cpp.html#105) for the error, but that wasn't terribly helpful, and the debugger will not provide the caller.

I don't know what is the problem since I can't debug, so I can't provide a minimal working example either. All of my code is working as expected, but I am sure I am providing Qt with something inappropriate, but I just do not know what. Any help on how to better debug this issue so I can determine what is causing it would be appreciated.

Interestingly, if I run in release and the assert is bypassed, the applications works exactly as expected with no obvious side effects (I do realize that could just be luck).

Comment: You can compile Qt from source and have the pdb files. I have for the most part used Qt built from source so I am not that experienced in what is provided by the online installer.

Comment: When you click [Retry] it breaks into the debugger, then open the stack frame view window and click up the stack frames (this will also open the source) until you find the problem.

Comment: There are no usable stack frames. It drops me back in main where I call `app.exec()` and the only stack frames above it are for Qtcored.dll and QtWidgetsd.dll, which provide no source for context

Comment: Related question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26674388/where-to-find-the-pdb-files-for-qts-dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26674388/where-to-find-the-pdb-files-for-qts-dll)

Comment: This may be a far stretch, but also downloading Qt sources (in Qt Maintenance Tool) and setting them in this [dialog](https://imgur.com/a/6rIPwWG) might help while stepping into Qt classes